# Do I need to install Mingw compiler components in Qt installation if i had already installed Mingw in my computer?

Tags: c++, qt

I installing Qt open source framework in my window 10 pc.  I already downloaded Mingw compiler and installed it to write C/C++. Now I wanna learn QT framework.  I using Qt online installer.  I choice to download custom compoment.  Do I need to selet mingw component to download if i had already installed?

Comment: I would install the version supplied with Qt for best results. You might be able to make it work with the other version but I suspect it would be much more of a headache.

Comment: You can add compiler from tools/options/kit . Don't forget to add mingw to your system path.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's not just one MinGW distribution and version out there. You can check out the exact supported version per Qt release at https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW .

Anyhow, if you install the pre-built Qt binaries via the online installer, the matching MinGW version will automatically be installed for you, and will be registered in Qt Creator so that things just work. There is actually no official way to prevent this.